# How to solve this "The getter 'length' was called on null"

Tags: json, http, flutter

I have a php file hosted on my college server and when i run this file on the server it works very well. I can get the json data after running my php file which is in the link http://www.alkadhum-col.edu.iq/Teachers%20Activities/get.php but when i was unable to got them when i had tried that in flutter on the app screen got "the getter 'length'was called on null".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
runApp(Workshops());
}

class Workshops extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext mycontext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO( 52, 73, 94, 1.0),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Don't show the leading button
        title: new Text("PHP with Flutter"),
        ),

        body: PostScreen(),
        )
    );
  }
}    

class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostScreenState createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
  List<Post> _postList = new List<Post>();

  Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('http://www.alkadhum-col.edu.iq/Teachers%20Activities/get.php');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      List<dynamic> values = new List<dynamic>();
      values = json.decode(response.body);
      if (values.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i] != null) {
            Map<String, dynamic> map = values[i];
            _postList.add(Post.fromJson(map));
          }
        }
      }
      return _postList;
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
      future: fetchPost(),
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            //dynamic post = snapshot.data[index];
            return (Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 8.0),
              child: new Card(
                elevation: 10.0,
                child: new Container(
                  child: new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].msg, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].day, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].date, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPost();
  }
}

class Post {
  String name;
  String msg;
  String day;
  String date;

  Post({this.name, this.msg, this.day, this.date});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      name: json['name'],
      msg: json['msg'],
      day: json['day'],
      date:json['date']
    );
  }
}
```

How to fix this issue?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the error stack trace? Post here please.

Comment: Which `.length` is causing the issue? As a side note, you shouldn't have to initialize `values` to a new list if you are just assigning the result of `json.decode` to it.

Comment: That depends, what `.length` is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at your link and tried running the code and I think the issue is in the data returned from your link.

```
[{"name":"م.م علي ستار باراني","msg":"امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ","day":"السبت","date":"2019-06-20"}][{"name":"م. امجد عباس التميمي","msg":"امتحان مادة هندسة البرامجيات اول فصلين","day":"الاحد","date":"2019-06-21"},{"name":"م.م علي ستار باراني","msg":"امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ","day":"السبت","date":"2019-06-20"}]
```

Right after the first object, you have a closing square bracket and no comma separating it from the opening square bracket beside it. Calling `json.decode()` on the link body throws the following error

```
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 115)
...,"day":"السبت","date":"2019-06-20"}][{"name":"م. امجد عباس التميمي","msg...
                                       ^
)
```

After fixing that, it runs fine for me. I tested by taking the body of the link manually and removing the offending characters, leaving me with the json below.

```
[{"name":"م.م علي ستار باراني","msg":"امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ","day":"السبت","date":"2019-06-20"},{"name":"م. امجد عباس التميمي","msg":"امتحان مادة هندسة البرامجيات اول فصلين","day":"الاحد","date":"2019-06-21"},{"name":"م.م علي ستار باراني","msg":"امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ","day":"السبت","date":"2019-06-20"}]
```

Running the app now displays the following:

[image: Screenshot of app]

Comment: Thank you material. The problem was in get.php file, so i need to move this line <br> print(json_encode(array_reverse($json_array), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)); after the closing curly bracket of the loop.

Comment: Now i have another problem which is the duplication of the records and i'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Yes and i did that before. Now how to solve the problem of duplication?.

Comment: @ASB Not trying to be rude, but you accepted my answer, not upvoted. Here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/MaterialTime/eb08031ecdf258f057e83fdec5488c4b) to the code I came up with, based on yours. The most recent time I tested it there was no duplication bug.

Comment: Dear you did it manually in line 46. By the way, i need to read from the php file itself on the server instead of initializing the whole json data objects.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think it didn't save properly when I switched it back. I think the issue is the `List<Post>` in the `_PostScreenState`. If you run the new code in the gist, it should not have the duplication glitch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195417/discussion-between-material-time-and-asb).

Answer (score 1):

make sure to always check for nulls in `itemCount` like this

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length == null ? 0 :snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index){}
),
```

With this if your list is null, the itemCount will return a 0.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this to the list `List<Post> _postList = []` that happens its that everything it a object in Dart so when you do this `List<Post> _postList = new List<Post>();` your variable _postList is equal to null because has been declared but not initialize so by default it null and you will not be able to use any property for the list until it initialize.

in resume just initialize your list like this: an empty list
 `List<Post> _postList = [];`

So you don't have that issue.

Comment: I did like you mentioed up but doesn't work. The problem is with length itself as i think but i'm confusing about the solution.